# Как раздавать фронтенд на Nginx из разных папок

Tags: nginx, location

Имеется такая конфигурация Nginx.Состоит из двух блоков server. Во втором блоке отдается фронтенд. Мне нужно отдавать фронтенд из разных папок в зависимости от url. Запрос типа example.ru/ отдает frontend1, а запрос типа example.ru/frontend2 соответственно отдает frontend2. Перепробовал уже самые разные комбинации настроек,взятых из похожих вопросов на stackoverflow, но у меня ничего не срабатывает. Папка "frontend2" в каталоге "name" есть.

```
server {
      listen 80;

      server_name api.example.ru;

      location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
      }

}



server {
      listen 80;

      server_name example.ru

   location / {

       root /home/name/frontend1;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

      }

    location /frontend2/ {

       root /home/name/;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Следующий location будет отдавать все URL начинающиеся с /frontend2 из папки /home/name/frontend2

```
    location ^~ /frontend2/ {

       root /home/name/frontend2;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

      }
```

После внесения изменений не забудьте перечитать конфиг.